# Is it possible to merge 2 hard drives into 1 big volume without losing data on of them?

Tags: centos, hard-disk, data

I got 2 connected hard drives in my CentOS 7 dedicated server, though only one is being used (already have data on it), while the other just sits there unpartitioned and unused. I want to 'add' the unused hard drive space to the main drive that is being used so it'll be one big volume, but I'm scared it might wipe out all of the data that is on the main drive.

Is there a way to make it happen without losing data?

Comment: Depends on how the system is set up. Is it using LVM?

Comment: Yes, LVM is there

Answer (score 3):

If your system is set up with LVM you can add the second drive as a physical volume (PV) to your existing volume group (VG). This will make the space on the second drive available in LVM. You can then use that space to expand an existing filesystem and/or to create a new disk partition for whatever purpose you want.

Steps:

1. Create a partition of type "Linux LVM" spanning the entire second disk.
2. Create an LVM PV from it with the `pvcreate` command.
3. Check the name of your existing VG with the `vgs` command.
4. Add your new PV to that VG with the `vgextend` command.
5. Verify the VG now has free space available by running the `vgs` command again.
6. Grow an existing partition with `lvextend` or add a new one with `lvcreate`.
7. Expand the filesystem in the grown partition with the appropriate command (`resize2fs` in case of ext4; in case of xfs, `lvextend` can do it for you) or create a filesystem in the new partition with `mkfs`.